# made changes in a branch but then checked out master then checked out the branch but none of my commits were there

Tags: git, git-branch

I have a working directory (master) and then i made a branch lets call it skrollr. I believe I was working in skrollr and making changes and commits. when i was in skrollr I dig `git branch` and i saw the star by skrollr so now I knew that the branch existed and i was working in it. I committed all then did checkout master, got back to the master working directory than checked out the skroller branch by `git checkout skrollr`it says that im in skrollr. but I don't see the commits I was working on before I switched to master. when i do `git log` it shows the commits it shows the commits form master but not from skrollr. I want to go to the working directory of skrollr.

Edit when i do `git branch -v` it shows the last commit from both branches are the last commit I made in master

Comment: do i have to do all the changes again?

Comment: What's the output of `git reflog`?  It shows the history of the commands that caused changes to HEAD (commits, checkouts, rebases, etc.).

Comment: I did what you said and i got my working directory back from doing `git checkout 9084e` i found 9084e from `git reflog` so that's good. I have to find out why i couldn't see my commits when i checked out branches. I see `* (detached from 9084e02)`  when i do `git branch`

Comment: The reflog should tell you what caused it.  Maybe you checked-out a commit?  See this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965676/why-did-my-git-repo-enter-a-detached-head-state).